# Put a 0 in front of digit <= 9 (for loop in r only working on the last instance)

Tags: r, for-loop, gsub

I've written this to find any instance of "1:" to "9:" and replace it with "01:" to "09:" whilst leaving "10:" or larger intact. Here's a sample script:

```
region = c("18:1-100","16:1-100","X:1-100","2:1-100","4:1-100")

to.replace=grep("^[[:digit:]]:", region)
replacement=grep("^[[:digit:]]:", region, value=T)
replacement=paste(0,replacement,sep="")

for (i in length(to.replace)){
  region[to.replace[i]]=replacement[i]
}
```

It only works on the last occurance in "region" therefore I think there's something wrong with my for loop, I just don't know what.

Comment: You are missing 1: in your loop, `for (i in length(to.replace))` -> `for (i in 1:length(to.replace))`

Comment: @Hemmo see `seq_len` for this

Comment: @Hemmo Many thanks, that works too! Now I feel like a numpty!

Comment: @Roland yes that would of course work also, just wanted to point the error in code, not an improvement. ;) alexwhan's solution is better anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace your for loop with:

```
region[to.replace] <- replacement
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run through it with an `lapply`...

```
region = c("18:1-100","16:1-100","X:1-100","2:1-100","4:1-100")
lapply( region , function(x){ r <- grepl("^[[:digit:]]:", x) ; ifelse( r , paste0( 0 , grep("^[[:digit:]]:", x , value=T) ) , x ) } )
```